# Should i create NewTopics in each service spring kafka?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka for sending messages between services. I use NewTopic bean for configuring number of partitions, for example:

```
 @Bean
    fun kafkaTopic(kafkaProperties: KafkaProperties): NewTopic = NewTopic(
        kafkaProperties.topics.schedulerCalculationTopic.name,
        kafkaProperties.topics.schedulerCalculationTopic.partitions,
        1
    )
```

My question is simple, should i add this bean into consumer service and producer service or only in one of them?

Comment: You could alternatively use Terraform or other tooling to create topics in a cicd pipeline rather than bundle it as part of your application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put it in the producer service and then consider the producer as 'owner' of those topics.

But it get a bit complicated if you have a scenario if you would have several producers to the same topic(s).

Comment: i'll have 2 or more instances of producer and some consumers, is it a problem in this case?

Comment: Oh, and ther is a problem. In one case consumer and producer will be in 1 app, that will have 2 or more instances

Comment: Several instances of same service (producer) i don't see as a problem, but if you would have different services that all produce to the same topic - then it could be a problem to say which of them that is the 'master/owner' of the topic :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not creating the topic on the fly, the best practice is to create topic before reading/writing to it.

Rationale is to prevent brokers to create topic whenever they receive metadata fetch request or consume request with the same topic name. Otherwise, if the consumer starts before the producer, you might end up wrong number of partition. (Broker will create your topic with default number of partitions setting.)